# ubuntu 22 does not recognize my headset microphone

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04, headset, audio-jack

I have Acer Nitro 5 laptop and I want to use my headset, when I plugged in it shows as a headphone. how do I fix that

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Nvidia GPU a0 HDMI/DP
Codec: Realtek ALC295
```

Comment: If your headset has only one plug (4 rings) and your laptop has different output and input connections then it should be blatantly obvious why the microphone isn't recognized, you need an adapter for that (or use it as headphones only).

Comment: hi, I use this headset on windows and it works perfectly but when I change it to ubuntu it works as a headphone